# Data is not updating in oracle database using php

Tags: php, oracle

i am using oracle with php. I have inserted data and now wants to update the column of availability of user. I am using the code given below but I am unable to update data. Data remains the same. Please help me.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['available']))
    {
        var_dump($_POST);
       print_r($_POST);
        echo("in available");
        session_start();
        $user = $_SESSION["username"];
        include('connect.php');
        $sql = oci_parse($conn,"select * from userM where user_name = '$user'");
       $result =  oci_execute($sql);

       while(($row = oci_fetch_array($sql,OCI_BOTH)) != false )
      {
         $p_No = $row[0];
         $full_Name = $row[1];
         $user_name = $row[2];
         $email = $row[3];
         $department = $row[4];
          $desig = $row[5];
        }
        $avail = 1;
        $sql1 = "update userM where user_name = '$user'"."set (:p_No, :full_Name, :user_name, :email, :department, :designation, :avail)";
           $compiled = oci_parse($conn,$sql1);
          oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':p_No', $p_No);
          oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':full_Name', $full_Name);
          oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':user_name', $user_name);
          oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':email', $email);
          oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':department', $department);
          oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':designation', $desig);
          oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':avail', $avail);
          oci_execute($compiled);
          oci_close($conn);
         header("location:register.php?msg=avail");
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: Your SQL is invalid - you're writing `"update ... where ... set"`, when the syntax is actually `"update ... set ... where"`. You really need to be checking the response from your `oci_execute` call. Also, you're using bindings for the update parameters, but substituting `$user` directly into the command text, which you should really tidy up.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie i rearranged the update statement but still its not working

Comment: Did you check what was returned by `oci_execute`? Also, you can use `oci_error` to see what went wrong. Sorry, I didn't read the rest of your sql text. You're using a combination of update and insert syntaxes. It should be something like `update userM set p_no = :p_no ... where user_name = :user`. http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I have done this too but still of no use $usql="update userM set avail=:avail where user_name=:user";
            $stmt = oci_parse($conn,$usql);

            oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":user_name", $user);
            oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":avail", $avail);

            oci_execute($stmt); 
             header("location:register.php?msg=avail");
            oci_commit($conn);

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie and there are no errors too

Comment: I see that in your last comment you said `oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":user_name", $user)`, but the parameter name within your sql text is actually `:user`. I also find it hard to believe there are no errors, as you should receive "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" when executing without having bound all variables. Did you call `oci_error` immediately after `oci_execute`?

Comment: One last thing - in your sample code in the comments above, you're calling `header` before `oci_commit`. I'm not familiar with the php engine, but that doesn't sound right - the commit should happen before the redirect (particularly since you'll want to handle any errors caused during commit).

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie ya i corrected it and it works perfectly thank u

Comment: If you just want to commit for a single oci_execute(), use the commit flag option instead of an explicit commit.  Check the PHP manual for details.

Answer (score 0):

### make this string before passing it to oci_parse($connection,$query) function:-

```
$query = 
"UPDATE 
   <table name>
   SET 
   <column name in capital> = '$update_name'
   WHERE 
   ID='$update_id'
";
```

---

where $update_name is a variable i recieved in $_POST['update_name']